# Jquery select everything but title

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to use jquery scroll function on everything but .title so I need to exclude .title from the selection. The selection must return .preview-container and .preview class with no .title class. I can't figure out how.

```
//React 

<div className="preview-container" ref={this.divRef} >
<h1 className="title">{title.toUpperCase()}</h1>
<div className="preview">   
   movieData.map(({id, ...otherProps}) => <CollectionItem key={id} id={id} {...otherProps} movies={movies} tvshow={tvshow}/>)
</div>
</div>

//Function

export const LeftArrow = (ref) => {
    var move = ref.current;
    $(move).animate({
        scrollLeft: '-=456px'
},'slow');
}
```

I tried using this but it instead is returning the title only

```
var cloneHtml = $( move ).clone().find('.title').remove();
```

Comment: because find() returns the element it finds.

Comment: `var $cloneHtml = $(move).clone(); $cloneHtml.find('.title').remove();`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of find() use the jQuery not() method:

```
var cloneHtml = $( move ).clone().not('.title');
```

https://api.jquery.com/not/